# StripeCheckout is not defined error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, stripe-payments

I'm using stripe but with custom form fields for the user introduce credit card number, card date to charge the card.

But when the "Confirm" button is clicked it appears an error:

```
Must provide source or customer.
```

This error maybe appears because on the console appears:

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: StripeCheckout is not defined"
```

With "            `Stripe.setPublishableKey({{config('services.stripe.key')}});`
" before the javascript code it appears:

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: pk_test_.... is not defined
        at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>
```

Do you know how to correct the issue?

RegistrationController charge():

```
public function charge(Request $request)
{
    Stripe::setApiKey(config('services.stripe.secret'));
    $source = $request->stripeToken;
    dd($source); //shows null
    Charge::create([
        'currency' => 'eur',
        'amount' => 1000,
        'source' => $source,
    ]);
}
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/charge', [
    'uses' => 'RegistrationController@charge',
    'as'   => 'registration.charge'
]);
```

Form:

```
<form action="{{ route('registration.charge') }}" method="post" id="paymentForm">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" id="stripeToken"/>
    <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
        <label class="text-gray">Card Number</label>
        <input type="text" required class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-lg-6 font-size-sm">
            <label class="text-gray">Date</label>
            <input type="text" required class="form-control"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group font-size-sm col-lg-6">
            <label class="text-gray">CVC</label>
            <input type="text" required class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" href="" id="confirmPayment"
     class="btn btn-primary" value="Confirm"/>
</form>
```

Then I have the javascript to integrate stripe:

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<script>
    let stripe = StripeCheckout.configure({
        key: "{{config('services.stripe.key')}}",
        image: "/square-image.png",
        locale: "auto",
        token: function(token){
            document.querySelector('#stripeToken').value = token.id;
            document.querySelector('#paymentForm').submit();
        }
    });

    document.getElementById('#confirmPayment').addEventListener('click', function(e){
        stripe.open({
            amount: 1000
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

If I pass the key directly like:

var stripe = Stripe({{config('pk_....')}});

It shows:

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Invalid value for Stripe(): apiKey should be a string. You specified: undefined.
```

Comment: From what I can tell, it looks like your token isn't set properly. The error message is the biggest indicator for me as its saying you tried to pass `undefined`. Please first hard code the key to see if the error goes away

Comment: Stripe Checkout is not included in your code. You have included Stripe.js which is a different product. If you want Stripe Checkout you need to load `https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js` instead as documented here https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom